# compare if substring exists within an existing list of files but with a different trailing name

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

I have 2 lists of filenames that I am comparing.

The first list is the full list of files in the directory, and the 2nd list is the list of files I've extracted from the directory with a specific filename format. I want to use this 2nd list, to find files in the full list that are slightly different in naming.

This is the code I have:

```
f = open('Sims4_62-62.txt', 'a')
dataread = listofGenFiles
print(listofGenFiles)

for genData in dataread:
    #counterRep = 0
    #print(genData)
    #print(dataread)
    if genData in fulldata and genData in 'Color_Front':
        if counterRep < 62:
            f.write(genData + '\n')
            counterRep += 1
            print(counterRep)       
f.close()
```

Example of filenames in genData:

> Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Left.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Right.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Back.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Left.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Right.npy
> Ea_S6D2_fC16_Color_Back.npy
> Ea_S6D2_fC16_Color_Left.npy
> Ea_S6D4_fC16_Color_Left.npy
> Ea_S6D3_fC15_Color_Left.npy

Excerpt from the full list from the directory with some files having the 'Front' variation in naming that wasnt initially taken in the 2nd list (From fulldata variable)

> Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Front.npy <--- I want this filename added to my file
> Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Right.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Back.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Left.npy
> Ea_S6D1_fC4_Color_Right.npy
> Ea_S6D2_fC16_Color_Front.npy  < ---- I want this filename added to my file
> Ea_S6D2_fC16_Color_Left.npy

How do I fix my code ? Not sure what I am missing here :)  thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'Color_Front' in genData`? E.g. you want to check if that string is a substring of the file name?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal no because `Color_Front` is not found in genData, it will only be in the `fulldata` list.

Comment: For that check to be true, `genData` should be something like `'Color'`, `'or_Fr'`, etc. Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I am not sure if that check is correct... so `genData` will contain something like `Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Right`, then I want to check that in `fulldata` it contains the substring of the above, with`Color_Front` so the file in `fulldata` that is called `Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Front`  will be found and written to my newfile,

Comment: Then the two should definitely be swapped like I mentioned.

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I tried swapping like this `if genData in fulldata and 'Color_Front' in genData:` but it still doesn't get the output I need :(

Comment: `if genData in fulldata and 'Color_Front' in genData:`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal yup just tried that but it doesn't find the files I need :(

Comment: Could you provide a clear example for `genData` and `fulldata`?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal I pasted the exact list of files that would be in genData and fulldata above :)  basically I'm trying to find the matching pair for the `Front` files

Comment: I see now. And I also see that `'Color_Front'` is in none of the elements from `genData`. Why is that check there in the first place?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal because I want the initial string to be present in the `Color_Front` name. So like if I have the filename `Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Back` in the `genData` , I want to find the matching pair for it for the `Front` which is only in `fulldata` now . so I want to find the  `Ea_S6D1_fC3_Color_Front` which is missing from genData but it is present in `fulldata`

Comment: To do that, a quick solution would be to do something like `'_'.join(genData.split('_')[:-1]) + "_Front.npy")` to replace the last word with `Front`. There are probably much nicer solutions using `os`, but this should work.